# Firebase: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token -> uncaught referenceError

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-app-engine, flask

In my web app, I am implementing Firebase's Google sign in authorization, but seeing a `SyntaxError` on site load, and `referenceError` on button `onclick`

[image]

My html code includes a button for sign in, and the Firebase scripts:

`<button onclick="login()">Sign In</button>`

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  ​
  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  ​
```

I have scrubbed the specific keys and Ids below to make the question more general, but they are correctly tied to a Firebase project.

```
  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "key",
      authDomain: "mywebsite.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://mywebsite.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "signup",
      storageBucket: "signup.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "senderId",
      appId: "appId",
      measurementId: "measureId"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
  </script>
```

And I am linking to a JS file `google_sign_in.js` (which is the correct path in my file structure)

`<script src="../static/js/google_sign_in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

My google_sign_in.js code is as follows:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    console.log("user signed in")​​
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    console.log("user signed out")
  }
});​​
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();​
function login() {
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    // ...
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
    var credential = error.credential;
    // ...
  });
}​
// sign signOut
function signOut() {
  // Sign out of Firebase.
  firebase.auth().signOut();
}​
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;​
if (user != null) {
  user.providerData.forEach(function(profile) {
    console.log("Sign-in provider: " + profile.providerId);
    console.log("  Provider-specific UID: " + profile.uid);
    console.log("  Name: " + profile.displayName);
    console.log("  Email: " + profile.email);
    console.log("  Photo URL: " + profile.photoURL);
  });
}
```

UPDATE - New javascript code and error screenshot of devtools:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) { // User is signed in.
    console.log("user signed in")
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    console.log("user signed out")
  }
});
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

function login() {
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    // ...
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
    var credential = error.credential;
    // ...
  });
} // sign signOut
function signOut() {
  // Sign out of Firebase.
  firebase.auth().signOut();
}
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user != null) {
  user.providerData.forEach(function(profile) {
    console.log("Sign-in provider: " + profile.providerId);
    console.log("  Provider-specific UID: " + profile.uid);
    console.log("  Name: " + profile.displayName);
    console.log("  Email: " + profile.email);
    console.log("  Photo URL: " + profile.photoURL);
  });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this was a tough one...

You have some sneaky hidden characters (`\u200b` - zero width space) in your code, probably due to copying and pasting from a web page.

Use the arrows keys in your text editor, and you will see the cursor skip these.  Delete them.

[image: invisible characters]

Comment: I went through over the weekend multiple times to make sure I got all the hidden characters from the JS code and the scripts in my html. I've updated my original post with the new JS code, and now on page load, `user signed out` appears automatically, and clicking the 'sign in' button flashes the pop up window (you can see the drop shadow of the box disappearing as I tried to time the screenshot). I went through again this morning and don't think there are any more hidden characters that are causing this..?

Comment: try `console.log(error)` inside your error catcher in `login()`

Comment: Just added `console.log(error);` right after `.catch(function(error) {`, but nothing is coming up on btn click in the devtools console. It looks identical to the latest screenshot

Comment: So, this has become a 2nd question.  You're going to have to log the sequence of events to see what is going on in your code. Log inside the `login() `function, and also the `logout()` function.  Please accept the hidden characters answer, then ask a new question logging the progress of events.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, thank you for the advise and support for the first issue